# Strange behaviour of \renewpagestyle from the titlesec package

Tags: header-footer, titlesec

The following code uses the `pagestyles` option and `\renewpagestyle` from the `titlesec` package to redefine the `plain` style:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=12cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\renewpagestyle{plain}
  {\setfoot{}{}{}\sethead{}{}{}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

The expected behaviour would be to clear all fields in both the header and footer; however, the result of the above example code is the following:

[image]

Why is the word "Contents" appearing in the header and in the footer?

Comment: This seems to be resolved if you formally issue a `\pagestyle{plain}` after setting it via `\renewstyle{plain}{..}`.

Comment: @Werner: but then all pages will have plain style, unless a manual change is done. Certainly that's not the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation of **titlesec** warns about using `\markboth` along with it. The `\tableofcontents` issues `\@mkboth` (which is usually equivalent to `\markboth`). One can cure the problem by saying

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@mkboth[2]{\chaptermark{#1}}
\makeatother
```

(which is something **titlesec** should do by itself).

Comment: What I don't understand is why the problem doesn't show up in `report` class, even though the code for `\tableofcontents` in the two classes is identical.

Comment: In addition to Alan's comment, in both classes `\@mkboth` is `let` exactly the same, either as `\markboth` or as `\@gobbletwo`, so yes, it's strange that the problem appears with `book` but not with `report`.

Comment: @Alan. Because `report` has `plain` as the main page style while `book` has `headings`. If `plain` is used as a "subsidiary" style with `\thispagestyle`, the main page style has to be (re)defined with `titlesec`, too. See the manual for further info. BTW, `\renewpagestyle{plain}{}` is shorter. (I'll realease a new version with many new features for page styles in a few days.)

Comment: @JavierBezos I'd say that the documentation is not very clear about that: it took me a while to understand that the explanation is in footnote 21.

Comment: @egreg. It should... and in fact it does. The problem is not in `\@mkboth`.

Comment: @JavierBezos: could you please clarify to me your last comment? According to egreg's answer it seems that the problem is `\@mkboth`, but you say that this is not the culprit. What is then the cause of the problem? Perhaps I am misunderstanding you previous comment?.