# Define pagestyle for TOC / LOF / LOT with titlesec

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec

I am using the `titlesec` package to define a rather simplistic pagestyle for the first pages of my chapter and the regular pages within a chapter:

```
\newpagestyle{main}{
  \headrule\sethead[\chaptername\ \thechapter:\ \chaptertitle][][]
                   {}{}{\thesection\ \sectiontitle}
  \footrule\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}

\newpagestyle{chapter_first_page}{
    \sethead[][][]{}{}{}
    \footrule\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{chapter_first_page}
```

I am failing, however, to apply that very same pagestyle to the pages for the table of contents and the list of figures. The closest I have come is using this:

```
\renewcommand*{\printtoctitle}[1]{\chapter*{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\printloftitle}[1]{\chapter*{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\printlottitle}[1]{\chapter*{#1}}
```

to get the TOC, LOF and LOT first page to be treated as a chapter. However, the pages are still missing the `\footrule` that should be part of the `chapter_first_page` style.

Also, if for example the LOF is longer than just a single page, the subsequent pages are not simply using the `main` pagestyle, but have "List of Figures" in both the header *and* the footer.

Any pointers regarding how to fix the problem and make the TOC / LOF / LOT pages fit in with the style of the rest of the document would be very much appreciated!

---

**Edit:** Here is a minimal working example that should illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[pagestyles, clearempty]{titlesec}

\usepackage[includefoot, includehead, bindingoffset=0cm,
            left=3cm, right=3cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpagestyle{main}{
    \headrule\sethead[\chaptername\ \thechapter:\ \chaptertitle][][]
    {}{}{\thesection\ \sectiontitle}
    \footrule\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}
\pagestyle{main}


\newpagestyle{chapter_first_page}{
    \sethead[][][]{}{}{}
    \footrule\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{chapter_first_page}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\LARGE\bfseries}
    {\centering\scshape
    {---~\chaptertitlename~\thechapter~---}}
    {-6pt}{\Huge}[]

\renewpagestyle{plain}{
    \sethead[][][]{}{}{}
    \footrule\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}

\renewcommand*{\printtoctitle}[1]{\chapter*{#1}}

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
(Include some title page here)
\newpage

\thispagestyle{chapter_first_page}
\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Test Chapter 1}
\lipsum[23-42]

\chapter{Test Chapter 2}
\lipsum[23-42]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As on the first page of a chapter, the default is the `plain` page style, `titletoc` has a command to redefine any page style, so try this`:

```
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\footrule
\sethead[][][]{}{}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}%
```

Comment: I have tried this before, but redefining the `plain` pagestyle like this leads to the problem described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37253/97669, i.e. suddenly there's a "CONTENTS" in both the header and the footer (similarly for the LOF / LOT).

Unfortunately, the fix described there using `\renewcommand\@mkboth` did not work for me (or I was putting the code in the wrong place).

Comment: Do you load also `titlesec`, or only `titleps`?

Comment: I am actually _only_ loading `titlesec`, with the following options if that is relevant: `\usepackage[pagestyles, clearempty]{titlesec}`. 
If I try to also load `titleps` I get a large number of errors, either because of "Incompatible package" (when trying to load it before `titlesec`), or "Command already defined" (when loading it afterwards).

Comment: You don't have to load  `titleps` if you use the `pagestyles` option. Could you post a minimal example code (b.t. w., do you redefine the chapters layout with `titleformat`?)

Comment: Yes, I do redefine the chapters layout using `titleformat`. I added a minimal working example now; I hope it covers everything relevant. It's from a thesis template which contains lots of packages and options, so it's hard to tell what are all the things that could play into the issue...

Comment: @der_herr_g: Unfortunately, there's some incompatibility between`memoir` and `titlesec`. I'll try to see tomorrow if something can be done.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! If it helps, I don't have very strong feelings about using `titlesec` — if a `memoir`-only based solution is easier, I'm also happy to just use that.